# Javascript form not returning a result when submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a mortgage calculator in Javascript.  When the submit button is pressed nothing happens. I appear to have no errors in my HTML or Javascript.

```js
function computeLoan() {
  var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
  var interest_rate =
    document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
  var months = document.getElementById('months').value;
  var interest = (amount * (interest_rate * .01)) / months;
  var taxes = document.getElementById('taxes').value;
  var insurance = document.getElementById('insurance').value;
  var escrow = (taxes + insurance) / 12;
  var loanPayment = amount * interest * (Math.pow(1 + interest,
    months)) / (Math.pow(1 + interest, months) - 1);
  var monthlyPayment = loanPayment + escrow;
  monthlyPayment.toFixed(2);
  monthlyPayment = document.getElementById('payment').value;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return computeLoan()" method="POST" action="javascript:;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Loan Amount</td>
      <td class="textbox"><input type="text" id="amount" min="1" max="10000000" onchange="computeLoan()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Mortgage Period (months)</td>
      <td class="textbox"><input type="text" id="months" min="1" max="360" onchange="computeLoan()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Interest Rate</td>
      <td class="textbox"><input type="text" id="interest_rate" min="0" max="100" onchange="computeLoan()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Property Taxes</td>
      <td class="textbox"><input type="text" id="taxes" min="0" max="10000" onchange="computeLoan()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Homeowners Insurance</td>
      <td class="textbox"><input type="text" id="insurance" min="0" max="10000" onchange="computeLoan()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Monthly Payment</td>
      <td class="textbox"><input type="number" id="payment" name="payment"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="button"><input type="submit" id="calculate" name="calculate" onclick="computeLoan()"></td>
      <td class="button"><input type="reset" name="Reset"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I expect the textbox for Monthly Payment to populate but nothing happens.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Don't feel like there are stupid, or easy questions.  We all start somewhere :D Can you show where you're adding the JS file?  My _guess_ is that you're DOM is rendering before your JS is loaded which means that your `onclick` doesn't have a method to attach to when it's rendered.

Comment: You set a variable called `monthlyPayment` but you don't do anything with it. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @VtoCorleone — No. Intrinsic event attributes don't work like that. As with any function, the variables referenced inside the function body is not accessed until the function is called.

Comment: You create the var `monthlyPayment` and then you set it to `loanPayment + escrow` and then you overwrite that and set it to the value of the payment element

Comment: i would recommend to not use a form unless you want to send the data to a webservice. You should write a Eventhandler for the button, so your calculation starts.

Comment: @louis12356 — Forms are an essential accessibility feature that groups form controls for screen readers, even if all the data is processed client side.

Comment: @louis12356 — There *is* an event handler for the button already

Comment: I *think* you just made a typo and got the left and right sides of `monthlyPayment = document.getElementById('payment').value;` the wrong way around.

Comment: I thought the variable monthlyPayment would be pulled into the payment id.  I changed the id and name in HTML to the same as my variable but I still get the same result.  Nothing.

Comment: @HCon — No, it's the other way around with the code you have. `a = b` copies the value of `b` into `a`.

Comment: @Quentin I see now.  That makes sense.  Thank you

Comment: Use `action="javascript: computeLoan"` instead of the `onsubmit` which is misplaced. Most people make this mistake -- `onsubmit` is not the proper place to script form submission. For one, it only fires if you use the submit button, not when you submit the form through any other means, including just pressing Enter on your PC keyboard in most user agents if that's what you use. Even though the "javascript: " scheme has never been standardized, it's by far the most applicable here, all options considered.

Comment: @amn — That's terrible advice. "onsubmit is not the proper place to script form submission" — yes it is! "For one, it is only submitted if you use the submit button, not when you submit the form through any other means, including just pressing Enter on your PC keyboard in most user agents if that's what you use." — That's absolutely untrue.

Comment: I stand corrected, pressing Enter does in fact submit the form as if from a button (importantly, firing the "submit" event), but it doesn't really matter, I was just trying to give one example where getting your semantics wrong (mistaking form pre-submission behavior that `onsubmit` lets you define, for actual form submission which is what `action` attribute is for) breaks your page slightly.

Comment: Not all forms are submitted through buttons or the keyboard, and rightfully they don't have to be. Invoking `submit()` on a form, for example, does not fire the "submit" event, as per [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-form-submit). Please stop this malpractice of coding form behavior with "onsubmit". You don't win anything by using it over the "action" attribute anyway. And nevermind, history will judge me. I've been doing forms since HTML 4.0 in 1998.

Answer (score 0):

In the `computeLoan` function, the last line you assign the `value` of your calculated field `#payment` (which is an empty string at this point) to the value that you just calculated before.

What you want to do is assign the calculated value `monthlyPayment` to the value property of the `input#payment` element.

So revert the assignment in the last line

```
monthlyPayment = document.getElementById('payment').value;
```

should become

```
document.getElementById('payment').value = monthlyPayment;
```

Additionally you are also executing the function multiple times.

1. The `onsubmit` of the form executes the function
2. The `onclick` of the submit button executes the function

Considering the `action` of the form you are not submitting the form, so you could reduce the code to

```
function computeLoan() {
  var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
  var interest_rate =
    document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
  var months = document.getElementById('months').value;
  var interest = (amount * (interest_rate * .01)) / months;
  var taxes = document.getElementById('taxes').value;
  var insurance = document.getElementById('insurance').value;
  var escrow = (taxes + insurance) / 12;
  var loanPayment = amount * interest * (Math.pow(1 + interest,
    months)) / (Math.pow(1 + interest, months) - 1);
  var monthlyPayment = loanPayment + escrow;
  monthlyPayment.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('payment').value = monthlyPayment;
}
```

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Loan Amount</td>
      <td class="textbox">
        <input type="text" id="amount" min="1" max="10000000" onchange="computeLoan()">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Mortgage Period (months)</td>
      <td class="textbox">
        <input type="text" id="months" min="1" max="360" onchange="computeLoan()">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Interest Rate</td>
      <td class="textbox">
        <input type="text" id="interest_rate" min="0" max="100" onchange="computeLoan()">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Property Taxes</td>
      <td class="textbox">
        <input type="text" id="taxes" min="0" max="10000" onchange="computeLoan()">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Homeowners Insurance</td>
      <td class="textbox">
        <input type="text" id="insurance" min="0" max="10000" onchange="computeLoan()">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labels">Monthly Payment</td>
      <td class="textbox">
        <input type="number" id="payment" name="payment">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="button">
        <button id="calculate" name="calculate" onclick="computeLoan()">
          Calculate
        </button>
      </td>
      <td class="button">
        <input type="reset" name="Reset">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Note that the button is not a submit anymore. And that the form is prevented its default action on submit only.

Additionally you can make the `computateLoan` only compute something when all values are defined

```
function computeLoan() {
  const amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
  const interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
  const months = document.getElementById('months').value;
  // This `let result = value1 || value2` is similar to the trenary operator 
  // `let result = value1 ?: value2` you might know from other labguages
  // `result` will evaluate to `value1` if that is not null or undefined, 
  // otherwise it will evaluate to `value2`
  const taxes = document.getElementById('taxes').value || 0;
  const insurance = document.getElementById('insurance').value || 0;

  if (amount && interest_rate && months) {
    let interest = (amount * (interest_rate * .01)) / months;
    let escrow = (taxes + insurance) / 12;
    let loanPayment = amount * interest * (Math.pow(1 + interest, months)) / (Math.pow(1 + interest, months) - 1);
    let monthlyPayment = (loanPayment + escrow).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('payment').value = monthlyPayment;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('payment').value = '';
  }
}
```

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROENKW

Comment: Thank you.  I changed it but now I am getting an error: I am getting the following error: The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: Does it state a line? Probably it tries to compute a value, but not all values are filled in yet

Comment: I filled in all the values and I got error for last line on my javascript code.  It highlights monthlyPayment as the issue.   the submit still does nothing

Comment: if you put a `console.log(monthlyPayment)` above `monthlyPayment.toFixed(2)`? what is the output?

Comment: I also think you should use the return value from `toFixed` like so `let monthlyPayment = (loanPayment + escrow).toFixed(2);`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: when I console.log(monthlyPayment) I don't get anything returned in the console.  This has beyond frustrated me.  I'm going to try the return value to toFixed now.

Comment: It didn't work.  Something has to be going on because I isolated the code from all my other HTML on an entirely new html doc and it still doesn't work.  Tried your code Pen link, I got nothing on the submit there either. Verified that chrome has javascript enabled. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Did you implement the `if` statement? Because if nothing is logged to the console it doesn't get there for some strange reason

Comment: I did implement it

Comment: Then before the `if` statement add 

`console.log(amount);`
`console.log(interest_rate);` and
`console.log(months);`
and see what their values are.

Comment: I'm getting an error on interest_rate if the number doesn't have a decimal.  Both taxes and insurance are returning NaN

Comment: I'm going to walk away from this for bit.  My brain is fried.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. In javascript, `console.log` is your friend

Comment: If you want I can give a bit more live help, so debug together. LMK

Comment: @HCon all your fields are text fields. Youll have to change them from strings to numbers to do what you want to do. `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`

Answer (score -1):

```js
function computeLoan() {
  // rest of the function


  var monthlyPayment = loanPayment + escrow;
  monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('payment').value = monthlyPayment;
}
```

Hey please update the last two lines of the function by assigning the value of monthlyPayment to the element.
This will work :)

Comment: I am just new here. Thanks for helping me to revise the answer. I will update it for the users to have it easy to understand

Comment: @AshutoshHans now I am getting the following error:  The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: this seems to work for me if I enter only the numbers in the input boxes, I can help you with the validations, while calculations you use parseFloat() to convert number strings to a number. 
It would be great if you can share what values you entered when this error generated.